# How to sort array of string by alphabetical order with domain based list

Tags: ruby

```
array = ["test-new.ramo.com", "analytics.ramo.com", "top-test.ramo.com", "ec2.new.ramo.com", "ccc.ramo.com", "ddd.kumar.ramo.com", "ccc.test.ramo", "ramo.com"]
```

I just need to display the results with domain based alphabetical orders.

Normal sorting it is giving

```
array = ["analytics.ramo.com", "ccc.ramo.com", "ccc.test.ramo", "ddd.kumar.ramo.com", "ec2.new.ramo.com", "ramo.com", "test-new.ramo.com", "top-test.ramo.com"]
```

Domain based components(from right side after . with alphabet order)

Expectation:

```
ramo.com
analytics.ramo.com
ccc.ramo.com
test-new.ramo.com
top-test.ramo.com
ddd.kumar.ramo.com
ec2.new.ramo.com
```

I want to display the results based domain(.com). After .com need to check the second subdomain name with alphabets(.ramo.com).

I have tried many ways not working based on domain(.com, .ramo.com, *.remo.com with alphabets).

Comment: This is a good problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: array.sort_by{|x|x.split('.').last}. But not exact results

Comment: You should not have a Rails tag as this is a pure-Ruby question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You where on the correct path with `array.sort_by{|x|x.split('.').last}`. The problem is that you now only sort by the last domain part and not the underlying sub-domains. Instead `reverse` the `split` result so it first sorts by `"com"`, then `"ramo"` followed by other the sub-domains.

```
array = ["test-new.ramo.com", "analytics.ramo.com", "top-test.ramo.com", "ec2.new.ramo.com", "ccc.ramo.com", "ddd.kumar.ramo.com", "ccc.test.ramo", "ramo.com"] 
array.sort_by { |domain| domain.split('.').reverse }
#=> ["ramo.com",
#    "analytics.ramo.com",
#    "ccc.ramo.com",
#    "ddd.kumar.ramo.com",
#    "ec2.new.ramo.com",
#    "test-new.ramo.com",
#    "top-test.ramo.com",
#    "ccc.test.ramo"]
```

This sorts the domains first based on the last part, then the second-last part etc.

The reason `"ddd.kumar.ramo.com"` is out of order compared with your expectation is because `"kumar" > "ccc"` and `"kumar" < "new"`. The same applies for `"ec2.new.ramo.com"`. If you want them in the exact same positions as specified in the question you need to sort by domain part count first.

```
array.sort_by do |domain|
  parts = domain.split('.').reverse
  parts.unshift(parts.count)
end
#=> ["ramo.com",
#    "analytics.ramo.com",
#    "ccc.ramo.com",
#    "test-new.ramo.com",
#    "top-test.ramo.com",
#    "ccc.test.ramo",
#    "ddd.kumar.ramo.com",
#    "ec2.new.ramo.com"]
```

Comment: You could replace `parts.unshift(parts.count)` with `[parts.count] + parts` which might be better readable if you don't encounter `unshift` often, but is less optimal since there are two additional arrays instantiated.

Comment: hi how to add one more sorting with the above results(priorities wise also i have to sort. any suggestion?

Comment: @RajkumarUlaganadhan I don't fully understand your comment. If you'd like to sort by additional factors you can simply add them to the parts array like I did with the part count. Array elements are compared from left (index 0) to right. You could for example do `[parts.count, another_criteria] + parts`, or `[parts.count] + parts + [another_criteria]` (you could also write this as `[parts.count, *parts, another_criteria]`).

Comment: Yes I want to add additional factors. thank you @3limin4t0r.